# Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `gap`. x non-numeric argument to binary operator i Input

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I am new in R and working with gapminder dataset to try out some plots.

This dataset is latest data downloaded from `gapminder website` which returns me an `error on mutate` where as `gapminder` data from `library(gapminder)` doesn't.

**df: gapminder_new**

```
gapminder_new %>%  
  select(country, "2010", "2019") %>%  head()

############## output ################
country 2010  2019
<chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>

Afghanistan 543 571     
Albania 4090    5210        
Algeria 4480    4710        
Andorra 40900   45900       
Angola  3590    3100        
Antigua and Barbuda 13000   15700
```

**Error:** getting an error on subtracting year's column values in `gapminder_new` df:

```
gapminder_new %>%  
  select(country, "2010", "2019") %>% 
  mutate(gap = "2019" - "2010") %>% head() 

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `gap`. x non-numeric argument to binary operator i Input `gap` is `"2019" - "2010"`. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

**But strange thing is when I use `gapminder data` from `library` and `shaped to similar wider format` then this one has no issues:**

**df: library(gapminder)** then it works

```
library(gapminder)

gapminder %>%
  filter(year == 1967 | year == 2007) %>%
  select(country, year, lifeExp) %>%
  spread(year, lifeExp) %>%
  mutate(gap = `2007` - `1967`) %>% head()

#################### output #########################

country 1967  2007 gap
<fctr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>

Afghanistan 34.020  43.828  9.808   
Albania 66.220  76.423  10.203  
Algeria 51.407  72.301  20.894
Angola  35.985  42.731  6.746   
Argentina   65.634  75.320  9.686
```

**Both dataset looks exactly same and I am trying to take difference of years which are `dbl` in all cases but it works in one case and not in other**.

What is going on here, where am I going wrong and how do I fix it?

Sometimes these small problems of data type returns which appears same visually in R dataframes are really frustrating.

It was not hard in moving from excel to python as it seems to be in moving from Python to R.

Answer (score 0):

it has now worked using `mutate(gap = .[["2019"]] - .[["2010"]] ) %>% head()` but I still don't know why this is required to work in `new gapminder dataset`  where as I didn't need to use this form with `library(gapminder)` dataset