# How to visually identify if returning data types is vector or list in r?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector, tidyverse

I am trying to learn R and have been facing some challenges possibly due to **returning different data types** which appears to be same as a `dataframe` or `tibble` but might have different datatype columns like `vectors or list` (Have explained data transformation example below).

(**UPDATE:** in short `spread() %>% mutate()` works but `select() %>% mutate()` doesn't work in same way which means `spread()` and `select()` returns different data types. All of it explained below with example)

**`library(gapminder )` data when `shaped to wider format` works without issues in subtracting year's values** inside `mutate` as shown below:

**Case1 df: `library(gapminder)`** (it works in this case)

```
library(gapminder)

gapminder %>%
  filter(year == 1967 | year == 2007) %>%
  select(country, year, lifeExp) %>%
  spread(year, lifeExp) %>%
  mutate(gap = `2007` - `1967`) %>% head()

#################### output #########################

country 1967  2007 gap
<fctr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>

Afghanistan 34.020  43.828  9.808   
Albania 66.220  76.423  10.203  
Algeria 51.407  72.301  20.894
Angola  35.985  42.731  6.746   
Argentina   65.634  75.320  9.686
```

**But when I use latest gapminder data downloaded from `gapminder website` gives an `error on subtracting years in mutate`.**

**Case2 `df: gapminder_new`**  (it doesn't work in this case)

```
gapminder_new %>%  
  select(country, "2010", "2019") %>%  head()

############## output ################
country 2010  2019
<chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>

Afghanistan 543 571     
Albania 4090    5210        
Algeria 4480    4710        
Andorra 40900   45900       
Angola  3590    3100        
Antigua and Barbuda 13000   15700
```

**Error:** getting an error on subtracting year's column values in `gapminder_new` df:

```
gapminder_new %>%  
  select(country, "2010", "2019") %>% 
  mutate(gap = "2019" - "2010") %>% head() 

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `gap`. x non-numeric argument to binary operator i Input `gap` is `"2019" - "2010"`. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

**to fix above error I had to use:**

`mutate(gap = .[["2019"]] - .[["2010"]] )`

**Why subtracting columns in both cases can't be done with same approach ?**

**So how can I make returning different data types appear different or put `identifying labels` if its `vector` or `list` which is usually the cause of problem.**

`single` `dbl` doesn't seems to be as helpful as `vector`, `list` can be to solve my problems**

*Note: I might be wrong in identifying it as a datatype issue or in explaining the challenge correctly that I am facing as I am new in R so kindly forgive.*

Original issue was raised at below link.

[Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `gap`. x non-numeric argument to binary operator i Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64367930/error-problem-with-mutate-input-gap-x-non-numeric-argument-to-binary-ope):

Comment: As you already guessed. This is not a datatype issue. The issue is that `2019` and `2020` are no syntactically valid names for variables (see eg `?make.names` on what's a syntactically valid name). To use such variables you have to put the names into "``" backticks as you did in your first code example. Putting quotes around such variables will work e.g. in `select` but will not work if you want to do computations as in `mutate` and will result in the error `non-numeric argument to binary operator` as e.g. `"2019"` is simply a character string.

Comment: @stefan but when I am using `library(gapminder)` data and spread() it even then I am taking years as column names and then I am mutating on it but it's working in that case. 

```{r}
gapminder %>%
  filter(year == 1967 | year == 2007) %>%
  select(country, year, lifeExp) %>%
  spread(year, lifeExp) %>% head()  
```

This also creates numeric column names: 1967 & 2007 which doesn't stop mutating a new column. If it doesn't work after select then its really a strange thing. It's strange things I am experiencing in R which I didn't face in learning python

Comment: Yep. In both cases your variables are numeric. The error "non-numeric" is not related to the datatype of the vars. But in your first example using the original gapminder dataset you have put 1967 and 2007 within backticks. That's why mutate works in that case, i.e. it knows that these are variable names. In the second example using new gapminder dataset you put 2010 and 2019 within quotes "". That's why mutate does not work, i.e. it does not understand that these are variable names. Instead it thinks you want to subtract the string "2010" from the string "2019" which does not work.

Comment: Yes, now its making sense: `select` was not accepting numerical names and I had to quote it and then numerical operations on string was not happening. I guess I will also have to be careful in future on how select behaves and how it can cause affect on summarising functions as well. Thanks alot for explaining so well, really helped alot to understand :)